# Drop Schema in Oracle: SQL Error: No more data to read from socket

Tags: oracle, schema, oracle11g

I'm trying to drop a schema in oracle 11g on our dev environment and I get back **SQL Error: No more data to read from socket**. There is no load on the schema as it's just a dev db. It's a small db without anything crazy going on. I see this error all the time. Restarting the instance sometimes resolves the problem. I can't seem to find any information that would point to a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this message often arises due to a bug. Also, when it appears an entry in your alert log and/or a trace file will contain more detail on what the error might actually be. To find your trace file for the session run:

```
select    U_DUMP.value
       || '/'
       || DB_NAME.value
       || '_ora_'
       || V$PROCESS.SPID
       || nvl2(V$PROCESS.TRACEID, '_' || V$PROCESS.TRACEID, null)
       || '.trc'
         "Trace File"
  from V$PARAMETER U_DUMP
       cross join V$PARAMETER DB_NAME
       cross join V$PROCESS
       join V$SESSION
         on V$PROCESS.ADDR = V$SESSION.PADDR
 where U_DUMP.NAME = 'user_dump_dest'
       and DB_NAME.NAME = 'db_name'                   
       and v$session.audsid=sys_context('userenv','sessionid');
```

Comment: I tried this command directly after I tried to drop the user. I still get the error 17410 "no more data to read from socket" and the query returns nothing. Sometimes even trying to access the schema after that point gives me a "No more data to read from socket" error again.

Answer (score 1):

A dba at my company gave me this one. It's

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE "SYS"."DROP_SCHEMA_FAST" (pSchema IN
    VARCHAR2)
IS 
    cnt NUMBER(5) := 0;
  sql1 varchar2(4000);
  x PLS_INTEGER;
--disable constraints:
  cursor cur1 is select 'alter table ' || OWNER ||'.'||table_name||' disable constraint '||constraint_name sql2
          from all_constraints where owner=pSchema and status='ENABLED'
          and table_name not like 'BIN$%' and constraint_name not like 'SYS_%' and constraint_name not like '%PK%';

  cursor cur2 is select 'alter table ' || OWNER ||'.'||table_name||' disable constraint '||constraint_name sql2 
          from all_constraints where owner=pSchema and status='ENABLED'
          and table_name not like 'BIN$%' and constraint_name not like 'SYS_%';  

--truncate all tables:
cursor cur3 is select 'truncate table ' || OWNER ||'.'||table_name sql2 from all_tables where owner=pSchema 
and table_name not like 'BIN$%';

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM dba_users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER(pSchema);
    IF (cnt <= 0) THEN
        RETURN;
    END IF;
    sql1 := 'ALTER USER ' || UPPER(pSchema) || ' ACCOUNT LOCK';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql1;

--disable constraints:  
FOR ao_rec IN cur1 LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ao_rec.sql2;
END LOOP;

FOR ao_rec IN cur2 LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ao_rec.sql2;
END LOOP;
--truncate all tables:
FOR ao_rec IN cur3 LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ao_rec.sql2;
END LOOP;

--drop schema:
sql1 := 'DROP USER ' || UPPER(pSchema) || ' CASCADE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql1;
exception when others then null; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem, got fixed by setting "PLScope identifiers:" to "None" in `Tools->Preferences ->Database->PL/SQL Compiler`

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: Well, thank you but I've already gone though this. It's something I did wrong with my answer? If so, I'll fix the problem! (and sorry for the bother)

Comment: Should I add something like documentation? It was just something that solved the problem for me, don't remember where I've found the answer exactly but that's all I did to make the error disappear.